# Cross Browser Testing with 3D on VMWare/virtualization?

Tags: css, cross-browser, cross-platform, vmware, virtualization

I need to do cross-browser testing for HTML5/CSS3.

I have an old box that's currently being unused, and I've been looking at VMWare Server and other virtualization solutions to make use of this idle box.

However, the caveat here is that VMWare Server does not provide 3D for guest machines.

We need to be able to test CSS3 3D (and later, WebGL) cross-browser and cross-OS.  WebGL is not necessary at this point, but it's a bonus.

I'm wondering what solutions are available.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), they have [experimental 3D support](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-video).

Answer (score 0):

VMware Workstation does support 3D. It is not free though. You could use VMware vSphere ESXi which also supports 3D for Guests although it can be fairly involved.

If these are no good, you could also look at using something like VMware ThinApp which would allow you to virtualise your browser on your current PC so you can run multiple different versions of IE etc. But this also has a cost.

Hope this helps.